# Implement a type in Python, for functions in a module (not class)?

Tags: python, typeclass, python-module, python-typing, abc

```py
def f(x, y):
    return x & 1 == 0 and y > 0

g = lambda x, y: x & 1 == 0 and y > 0
```

Now the same thing in Haskell:

```hs
import Data.Bits

f :: Int -> Int -> Bool
f x y = (.&.) x 1 == 0 && y > 0
```

That works, however this doesn't:

```hs
g = \x y -> (.&.) x 1 == 0 && y > 0
```

Here's the error this gives:

```
someFunc :: IO ()
someFunc = putStrLn $ "f 5 7: " ++ ( show $ f 5 7 ) ++ "\tg 5 7: " ++ ( show $ g 5 7 )

• Ambiguous type variable ‘a0’ arising from the literal ‘1’
  prevents the constraint ‘(Num a0)’ from being solved.
  Relevant bindings include
    x :: a0 (bound at src/Lib.hs:13:6)
    g :: a0 -> Integer -> Bool (bound at src/Lib.hs:13:1)
  Probable fix: use a type annotation to specify what ‘a0’ should be.
  These potential instances exist:
    instance Num Integer -- Defined in ‘GHC.Num’
    instance Num Double -- Defined in ‘GHC.Float’
    instance Num Float -- Defined in ‘GHC.Float’
    ...plus two others
    ...plus one instance involving out-of-scope types
    (use -fprint-potential-instances to see them all)
• In the second argument of ‘(.&.)’, namely ‘1’
  In the first argument of ‘(==)’, namely ‘(.&.) x 1’
  In the first argument of ‘(&&)’, namely ‘(.&.) x 1 == 0’
   |
13 | g = \x y -> (.&.) x 1 == 0 && y > 0
   |                     ^
```

How do I get the same error in Python? - How do I get errors when the input doesn't match expectations?

To be specific, how do I say that a function/lambda MUST have:

- arity of 5
- each argument must be numerical
- each argument must implement `__matmul__` (`@`)
- return `bool`

I know that I can roughly do this with: (docstrings and/or PEP484) with `abc`; for classes. But what can I do for 'loose' functions in a module?

Comment: Your Haskell example seems to be completely unrelated to what you're asking for. The Haskell example is a two-argument function where type inference can't deduce enough information, while the thing you're asking for in Python has 5 arguments, different requirements on the arguments, and no type inference.

Comment: Also, "must be numerical" isn't a well-defined requirement.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Yeah I'm trying to generalise to other problems by specifying those constraints. Numeric types https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Type_basics_II#Numeric_types https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#numeric-types-int-float-complex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One trick I found was to use [Callback Protocols](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/protocols.html#callback-protocols):

```python
from typing import Optional, Iterable
from sys import version_info

if version_info > (3, 8):
    from typing import Protocol
else:
    from typing_extensions import Protocol


class Combiner(Protocol):
    def __call__(self, *vals: bytes, maxlen: Optional[int] = None) -> list[bytes]: ...
```

Applied to my problem, just duplicate:

```python
def combiner0(*vals: bytes, maxlen: Optional[int] = None) -> list[bytes]: return []
def combiner1(*vals, maxlen = None): return []

# Unused var just for type checking
_combiner: Combiner = combiner0
_combiner: Combiner = combiner1
del _combiner
```

Answer (score 1):

Generally you have three possible approaches:

1. Let the runtime produce errors for incompatible operations (e.g. `1 + 'foo'` is a `TypeError`).
2. Do explicit runtime checks for certain attributes; though this is usually discouraged since Python uses duck typing a lot.
3. Use type annotations and a static type checker.

Your specific points:

> - arity of 5

Define five parameters:

```
def f(a, b, c, d, e): ...
```

> - each argument must be numerical

Either static type annotations:

```
def f(a: int, b: int, c: int, d: int, e: int): ...
```

And/or runtime checks:

```
def f(a, b, c, d, e):
    assert all(isinstance(i, int) for i in (a, b, c, d, e))

def f(a, b, c, d, e):
    if not all(isinstance(i, int) for i in (a, b, c, d, e)):
        raise TypeError
```

`assert`s are for debugging purposes and can be disabled, an explicit `if..raise` cannot. Given the verboseness of this and the duck typing philosophy, these approaches are not very pythonic.

> - each argument must implement `__matmul__` (`@`)

The most practical way is probably to let the runtime raise an error intrinsically if the passed values do not support the operation, i.e. just do:

```
def f(a, b):
    return a @ b  # TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for @: ... and ...
```

If you want static type checking for this, you can use a `typing.Protocol`:

```
from typing import Protocol

class MatMullable(Protocol):
    def __matmul__(self, other) -> int:
        pass

def f(a: MatMullable, ...): ...
```

In practice you probably want to combine this with your previous "each argument must be numerical" and type hint for a type that fulfils both these requirements.

> - return `bool`

```
def f(...) -> bool: ...
```

---

Especially given that the `@` operator is mostly used by 3rd party packages like numpy, in practice the most pythonic implementation of such a function is probably something along these lines:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import ndarray

def f(a: ndarray, b: ndarray, c: ndarray, d: ndarray, e: ndarray) -> bool:
    return np.linalg.det(a @ b @ c @ d @ e) > 0  # or whatever
```

You can't directly translate the same typing expectations from Haskell to Python. Haskell is an insanely strongly typed language, while Python is almost the complete opposite.

---

To type hint a higher order function that accepts such a function as argument, use `typing.Callable`:

```
from typing import Callable

def hof(f: Callable[[ndarray, ndarray, ndarray, ndarray, ndarray], bool]): ...
```

Comment: Thanks, [`Protocol`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Protocol) could be what I was looking for. The naming sounds like the keyword I use in Swift. I avoided the `typing` module because Python 2; but it's about time to drop support for that. Protocol is Python 3.8 though, not sure if I want to break support for 3.6 and 3.7 also… - thanks for your analysis also